# Crash when referencing a vector of Com_Ptrs through a pointer in a struct, vector size unknown

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, struct, directx-11

The following function works when called from a pointer to the class containing it. However, when the class containing this function is initialized inside of a struct, and then called on the instance **inside** of that struct, from another class, it crashes.

In the latter case, when the thing is 2 layers deep inside a struct, while debugging, the array size is unknown.
in the **working** case, while debugging the array size **is** known
no idea why it behaves differently, everything else is the same.

(Declared in the header:)

```
vector<Microsoft::WRL::ComPtr <ID3D11ShaderResourceView>> _textureViews;

ID3D11ShaderResourceView** TextureClass::GetTextureArray()
{
    return _textureViews[0].GetAddressOf();
}
```

Here is the full code. Any insight would be much appreciated, thanks.

https://github.com/mister51213/DirectX11Engine/blob/Restructure/DirectX11Engine/GfxUtil.h

Comment: Post a [mcve] please. Not descriptions of one.

Comment: Bear in mind that adding or removing to a vector will invalidate any previous return values of GetTextureArray. If you don't need to actually replace the object being managed maybe you should just return the interface pointer

Comment: What do you do with the return value? If you try to treat it as an array, that's not going to work. A ``vector<ComPtr>`` can't be treated as if it were an ``array<ID3D11ShaderResourceView*>``. What are you doing here?

Comment: @M.M Sorry I don't really understand what you mean. Can you please elaborate? How do I return the interface pointer?

Comment: @ChuckWalbourn Elsewhere in the code (inside LightShaderClass::SetShaderParameters), I pass the ID3D11ShaderResourceView** returned by gettexturearray() into this function: deviceContext->PSSetShaderResources(0, 6, textureArray); which is an ID3D11DeviceContext function.

Comment: Btw I think M.M means pass the whole Com pointer in instead of a ID3D11ShaderResourceView** double pointer? But I tried that and the directx function doesnt want a comptr, it wants the raw double pointer, thats why I need to get teh address of teh compointer.

Comment: If you are passing a single shader resource, that works. If you are passing an array of shader resources, you need to build one that's actually an array of ``ID3D11ShaderResourceView*``. Typically that would be a temporary on the stack: ``ID3D11ShaderResourceView* srv[] = { texture1.Get(), texture2.Get() }; deviceContext->PSSetShaderResources(0, _countof(srv), srv); ``. See [ComPtr](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/ComPtr)

Answer (score 0):

Oops it was just sloppy coding. I was masking the local pointer inside the material struct initialize function with another in-scope pointer to texture array, so the member variable version wasnt even getting initialized. Nothing to do with structs or ComPointers. Thank you for all your help.